# How to make .NET application look windows 8ish

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-8

So windows 8 and its metro look is here... Is there a standard/correct way to make an application have that same look in .NET?

I guess I haven't been Googling the right thing, because I can't seem to find much on it. And VS2012 seems to produce the old looking applications.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doubt there's anything off-the-shelf that does this, because the easiest solution is to just use the Metro API. Barring that, you can try using DevExpress widgets which have themeing support, or you can do custom painting for your controls.

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to winforms for a Metro look?

Comment: @Blam - Its more just out of curiousity...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, DevExpress has a Metro theme for WinForms: http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/DXv2/index.xml?page=47

Of course, this means you have to have DevExpress, which costs money, but is also very good.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a took also to [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/).

Comment: +1 But note that this appears to be a WCF solution, although the question is tagged WinForms.